# how to update the same record several times in a queueable apex chain?

Tags: apex

**Scenario**

`after insert` of Sobject `Request__c` is fired.

- `after insert` enqueues an instance of `Class1`.
- `Class1`:

  - selects the inserted record (using the received Id from `after insert`);
  - changes `Status__c` from `awaiting` to `processing`;
  - update the record;
  - creates an instance of `Class2`, pass the record into `Class2` instance and enqueues `Class2` instance;
- `Class2`:

  - Do nothing with the record;
  - creates an instance of `Class3`, pass the record into `Class3` instance and enqueues `Class3` instance;
- `Class3`:

  - Do a REST API call;
  - changes `Status__c` from `processing` to `done` on the record;
  - update the record;

**Expected result**

`record.Status__c` is `done`.

**Actual result**

`record.Status__c` is `processing`.

**More info**

In `Class3`, I tried to select the record again before update but I got the same result;

**Does anybody can explain to me why `Class3` update statement "doesn't work" while the update statement on `Class1` works?**

Comment: Your update in "Class3" should work. We can't really help you out too much without seeing the actual code though. If you haven't done so already, you need to check to see if  "Class3" is running into any errors. In async apex, you generally need to send an email or somehow otherwise persist the state of the operation (e.g. by writing it to a record of another SObject). Transaction finalizers could help you with that.

Comment: The other thing that you can do is to simply call the `execute()` method and pass `null` in for the context (which 99% of people never use because it only contains the execution id). Set yourself up and make this call synchronously via anonymous apex, and you'll be able to actually (easily) get an execution log so you can look for issues.

Comment: Hey Derek, you comment is correct. An error was happening and I wasn't seeing it. Good job man.

Comment: By the way, this error happened because the code responsible to mark it as failed is not working: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/402904/why-an-update-in-the-catch-block-doesnt-work

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [Derek](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/24889/derek-f) (thanks man) in the comments, an error was happening do the update clause wasn't being executed.
Once this issue was solved, it leads to another problem I posted [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/402904/why-an-update-in-the-catch-block-doesnt-work).