# Why an update in the catch block doesn't work?

Tags: apex

Check the following code

```java
try {
    createPostOnSlack();
    setSlackPostRequestStatusToDone();
}
catch (Exception caughtException) {
    setSlackPostRequestStatusToFailed();
    throw caughtException;
}
```

this is the code on `setSlackPostRequestStatusToFailed`:

```java
void setSlackPostRequestStatusToFailed() {
    slackPostRequest.Status__c = 'Failed';
    update slackPostRequest;
    Database.setSavepoint();
}
```

**Expected result**

`record.Status__c` to be equal to `Failed` at the end of the method.

**Actual result**

`record.Status__c` is equal to `Processing` at the end of the method.

**More info**

- `slackPostRequest` is not null and it does have Id.

**Does anybody know why the update in the `catch` clause is not working?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `update` works as expected, but right after it you re-throw the exception, so the transaction fails, therefore Salesforce rollback the whole transaction which includes the `update` in the catch block.

Instead of updating the record you could publish a platform event setted as `Publish Immediately`, then you could handle it changing the status of the record.
It will be handled in a new transaction, so the exception will not rollback it.

Comment: Alternatively, if you don't _need_ the exception for anything else and processing can continue, simply not re-throwing the exception would work.

Comment: So here is the thing fellows: I was expecting that `Database.setSavepoint()` would tells the platform to rollback everything up to the point where the savepoint was defined. Am I misunderstanding anything here?

Comment: @Saulo an uncaught exception (one that reaches the entry point of the transaction, as your re-thrown exception probably does) will always roll back the entire transaction. Setting a savepoint here doesn't change that. This seems like it might be getting into X-Y problem territory.

Comment: @Saulo `Database.setSavepoint()` is meant to be used with `Database.rollback(savepoint)`. Calling only `Database.setSavepoint()` without saving the result you're only wasting DML (it counts towards governor limits)

Comment: Appreciate your comments folks! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

An uncaught exception undoes almost everything. If you want to signal an error to the client *and* still have the record update, use a platform event that uses the Publish Immediately property. After that, set up a Platform Event Trigger to update the record's status field.

```
try {
    createPostOnSlack();
    setSlackPostRequestStatusToDone();
}
catch (Exception caughtException) {
    setSlackPostRequestStatusToFailed();
    throw caughtException;
}

void setSlackPostRequestStatusToFailed() {
    AsyncDml__e asyncDml = new AsyncDml__c();
    slackPostRequest.Status__c = 'Failed';
    asyncDml.Payload__c = JSON.serialize(slackPostRequest);
    asyncDml.Operation__c = 'update';
    EventBus.publish(asyncDml);
}
```

Where `AsyncDml__e` is a platform event with a trigger:

```
trigger ProcessAsyncDml on AsyncDml__e (after insert) {
  for(AsyncDml__e busEvent: Trigger.new) {
    if(busEvent.Operation__c == 'update') {
      sObject record = (sObject)JSON.deserialize(busEvent.Payload__c, sObject.class);
      update record;
    }
  }
}
```

Obviously, the above code breaks all the rules (DML in loop, etc), this code is only meant to be a demonstration of what the process would look like.

Comment: Thank you sfdxfox. That serialization is what bothers me. I was thinking o a queueable class to do the update. I like the queueable class because I can pass not only the record but the exception and anything else I need to use in order to update the log.
Do you see any problem with this approach?

Comment: @Saulo You can either throw the exception with the Platform Event, or you cannot throw the exception, and will need a different mechanism to signal an error to the client. Queueables, batchables, schedulables, future calls, etc are all rolled back if you throw an unhandled exception.